# Magento 2 custom module Class does not exist

Tags: magento2.4.1, magento-2-commerce

I am using the custom module for minicart qty increment and decrement,

Module: https://github.com/kirtinariya1/MinicartAjaxQtyIncrementDecrement

After the installed module visible, but value not increased and decreased,

console Error:

[image]

Report log:

```
{"0":"Class Mymodule\\MinicartQty\\Controller\\Sidebar\\UpdateItemQty\\Interceptor does not exist","1":"#1 Magento\\Framework\\Code\\Reader\\ClassReader->getConstructor('Mymodule\\Minicart...') called at [vendor\\magento\\framework\\ObjectManager\\Definition\\Runtime.php:54]\n#2 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Definition\\Runtime->getParameters('Mymodule\\Minicart...') called at [vendor\\magento\\framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer.php:48]\n#3 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create('Mymodule\\Minicart...', array()) called at [vendor\\magento\\framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager.php:56]\n#4 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->create('mymodule\\Minicart...') called at [vendor\\magento\\framework\\App\\ActionFactory.php:44]\n#5 Magento\\Framework\\App\\ActionFactory->create('Mymodule\\Minicart...') called at [vendor\\magento\\framework\\App\\Router\\Base.php:306]\n#6 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Router\\Base->matchAction(&
```

Comment: It should be Mymodule.. & remove generated also.

Comment: Pls check my updates.

Comment: Yes, i removed generated, still i am getting class issue.

Comment: Can you please upload UpdateItemQty.php this controller code with file path ?

Comment: @RohanHapani Path : app\code\Mymodule\MinicartQty\Controller\Sidebar\UpdateItemQty.php code:https://codeshare.io/2W3kJW

Comment: @zus, did you changed module name from `Kcn` to `Mymodule` ?

Comment: @Pawan  Yes, right.

Comment: there may be possibility that you forgot to change vendor name from  Kcn to Mymodule for any file..first try to install module as it is.

Comment: I am searching the name kcn with whole folder, I am updated name.

Comment: hi pawan, anything else missed out.

Comment: @RohanHapani anything else missed out?

Comment: I am getting this error,

{"readyState":4,"responseText":"<br />\n<b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot declare class Kcn\\MinicartQty\\Model\\Sidebar, because the name is already in use in <b>C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\m3\\app\\code\\Mymodule\\MinicartQty\\Model\\Sidebar.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />\n","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}

Comment: Sidebar.php : https://codeshare.io/5Nw741